# Solving system of equations with summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

Is there a way to express $y_t$ in terms of $\delta$ and $p_t$ in the following system?

$$
\begin{cases}
& \sum\limits_{t=0}^{\infty}\delta^t\cfrac{p_t}{p_t+(1-p_t)y_t}=K \\
& p_{t}=\cfrac{p_{t-1}}{p_{t-1}+(1-p_{t-1})y_{t-1}} \\
& p_0=\hat{p}
\end{cases}
$$
with $K>0$, $0<p<1$, $0<\delta<1$, $0\leq y_t\leq 1$, and $\hat{p}>0$ given.

Comment: Not sure this is doable, but one should note that, for every $t$, $$p_t=\frac{\hat p}{\hat p+(1-\hat p)y_0y_1\cdots y_{t-1}}.$$

Comment: Thank you @Did! This may help. Could you please provide me with an intuition of proof for the property you report?

Comment: Induction on $t$.